# Boost.Asio File Uploading Headers

Tags: c++, boost-asio

This is what I am using while posting text data (i.e. name=Boxxy&age=18)

```
            ostream request_stream(&request);
            request_stream << "POST " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
            request_stream << "Host: " << host << "\r\n";
            request_stream << "User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0\r\n";
            request_stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
            request_stream << "Content-Length: " << data.length() << "\r\n";
            request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
            request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
            request_stream << data;
```

And, while posting a file, I am trying to use this:

```
            ifstream fin(file.c_str(), ios::binary);
            ostringstream buffer;
            buffer << fin.rdbuf();
            string ctn(buffer.str());
            boost::asio::streambuf request;
            std::ostream request_stream(&request);
            request_stream << "POST " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
            request_stream << "Host: " << host << "\r\n";
            request_stream << "User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0\r\n";
            request_stream << "Content-Type: image/png\r\n";
            request_stream << "Content-Disposition: attachment;name=file;filename=a.png\r\n";
            request_stream << "Content-Length: " << ctn.length() << "\r\n";
            request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
            request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
            request_stream << ctn;
```

This code returns 1, but nothing happens on PHP side. I also tried to use PUT instead of POST. And different Content-Types. Is something wrong with my headers, or should I do something different from normal POST request?

Comment: "The code returns 1" - WHAT? Also, why not just `request_stream << fin.rdbuf()`?

Comment: `request_stream << fin.rdbuf()` makes no change.
By saying returns 1, i meant my POST successfully reaches to the host.